# Store secrets from appsettings.json file in .Net Console Application on Azure Key Vault

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-keyvault

I have a .Net Core console application which retrieves raw data, then applies a Kusto query and finally uploads them on azure. I have the client secrets stored in the appsettings.json file. However, this is not a good practice since they should never be stored there. I would like to know how can I store the following information on **Azure Key Vaults** (BlobConnectionString, KustoConnectionString, ClientId, ClientSecret, ApplicationInsights Instrumentation Key) which are found in the appsettings.json file. I found several documentations about azure key vaults related to .Net Core Web Apps but I didn't find anything related to **Console Applications**. What are the exact steps to do so? Should I first create a key vault service. Or should I do something before? What should I do then with the values of the keys mentioned above in the appsettings.json and is there a code sample which is ready used to directly retrieve the values stored in the Key Vaults so when I execute my code it will normally work like before.

I would really appreciate it if someone can give me an idea how to do that and if there are any previous code samples related to the same subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KeyVault can be added to any .net core application by using `AddAzureKeyVault`, and then accessing it in exactly the same way as other configuration providers (File: appsettings.json, UserSecrets, Environment variables).

Full example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
        {
            config.AddAzureKeyVault(
               new SecretClient(
               new Uri("Your Key Vault Endpoint"),
               new DefaultAzureCredential()),
               new AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions())
           {
               ...
           });
        })
```

Comment: Thank you your answer. In my case, since it is a console application I don't have a IHostBuilder. So how can I use the ConfigureAppConfiguration in the main program.cs file ?

Comment: You can still use Host.CreateDefaultBuilder in a console app.

Comment: I just have a question regarding KeyVault. What are the requirements to use it ?  What should I do on azure. Since I don't have a hosted app on Azure. Does it work with only using the keyvault resource or should I also have a registered app with active directory ? How will I be able to use KeyVault in my .NET Console Application so that I would be able to save all passwords there. In the CreateDefaultBuilder you mentioned above, let us suppose that I have 2 json files and each one of them contains secret information. How can I configure both to use keyvault ?

Comment: If you currently have passwords in 2 separate appsettings.json, then they can all be moved to a single keyvault.  Your program will remain exactly the same (asuming you are reading the configuration via IConfiguration/GetSection/GetValue etc).  Json files, environment variables, keyvaults are all just simple key/value stores.

Comment: Can you please provide me with a sample on how it works because I am really confused with all this IConfiguration in order to use both appsettings.json files. What should I write in the code you provided above in order to configure each json file ? How does this ConfigureAppConfiguration work ? How will it know which json file to work with ?

Comment: How will keyvault know which json file to configure. Let us suppose that I have a clientsecret in one of the 2 json files. How should I configure the code above to configure this json file with the keyvault configuration for it then to be used in the program.cs file.

Comment: Keyvault and Json files are 2 completely different methods of doing the same thing (storing configuration data).  Keyvault doesn't understand json, it's a key/value store, effectively a database.

Comment: Then how will I get the value of the secret from the given json file using key vault. If I have the json file { "Secret" : "password"}. This password should be removed from the json file and be replaced from the value stored in key vault. My question how will it be accessed in the console application in the program.cs file. What should I do to get the value ?

Comment: If you currently use IConfiguration (like you do with asp.net), then it will 'just work'.  If you currently have these passwords in appsettings.json, and you move them to KeyVault, then it's transparent, and your code will continue to work.  The caveat is that you must name your keyvault keys to match the way you have them in appsettings.json, with double underscore between the child/parent.   `Credentials__UserName` for example.   If you aren't using IConfiguration/appsettings, then you should start doing so, as it's the way configuration is done in .net

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. One last question, related to the second json file which also contains information. How will I do the configuration of the 2 json files together. If I store the values in Azure will it automatically know the value of the secret based on the child/parent matching even if I have two json files ?

Comment: The 2 json files have different child/parent don't they?  There shouldn't be any overlap.